# React parent to child props passing without rerender

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-props, editorjs

I have a button on my parent component and a third-party form in a child component. When the user clicks the button, the save function in the child component should run. This is my plan.

**Method 1 I tried:**
1.Created a variable on parent called `save`.
2. When button is clicked, save becomes true
3. Save is passed down to the child as props
4. Child contains a useEffect() which listens to changes in props.save
5. If props.save is true, save function of child component runs

**Method 2 I tried:**

1. Instead of passing props, I created a react-redux store.
2. The store contains save variable which is false by default
3. When button is clicked, save in redux becomes true
4. I use useSelector() hook to listen to the save variable change, inside the child component
5. UseEffect is used to run the save() function when the value change is detected

What happens with both methods is that I am losing the data in my child component because the variable change in the parent causes a page refresh. Therefore I want to pass the data down to the child, without causing rerenders. What are the options I have?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no options because your child needs an updated value from false - true . This won't happen unless you re-render

Comment: What option do I have to trigger the save() function in my child component when the button in the parent component is clicked?

Comment: As i said there is no other option AFAIK . If there has to be something then i am pretty sure its an hack . But i am not aware of it :-(

Comment: so what is the problem here , your form in the child component gets cleared ?

Comment: I've been struggling with this issue for a long time. It is part of the requirement :( I've seen Shopify store admin panel with similar functionality. Button outside the form component

Comment: Yes. I'm using react-editor-js here. Let me see if I can spin up a codesandbox on this issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233545/discussion-between-sachin-titus-and-shyam).

Comment: what third party form are you using? does it accept an onSubmit function and an id? You can have a button anywhere , just make sure to pass the form id to the button and then it can submit your form even if it's in a child component. <button type="submit" form="your-form-id>submit form</button>

Comment: @JelteHomminga I'm using react-editorjs

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Shyam, I could finally solve this issue!

My assumption that `useState` and `props` cause render was correct. And as @Shyam suggested, there is no direct way to avoid it.

I am using react-editor-js in my project and that's what caused the issue

```
  <EditorJs
    instanceRef={()=>{//code to save the reference as state variable}}
    enableReInitialize
    data={{}}
    tools={EDITOR_JS_TOOLS}
  />
```

The reason for state loss was that my `instanceRef` was being reassigned every time the component renders.

This reassignment can be prevented by wrapping the method to save the reference as a state variable with `useCallback()`